# How do I connect an UIBarButtonItem to the IBAction of ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am in a situation where I need to collect the data from a ViewController and pass it to another ViewController. My only issue is doing this when the user presses an UIBarButtonItem.
Now if I understand this correctly the UIBarButtonItem's parent is the UINavigationController. So how do I go about solving my problem?

Here is a screenshot of the view in question along with the button(Review e-Mail) that is supposed to seque to the next View along with passing data to it.

[image]

I hope that I've managed to explain what my issue is. Basically what I would like to be able to do is something along these lines :

```
-(IBAction) reviewEmailButtonWasPushed: (UIBarButtonItem*)senderRecieved
{
    ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNib=@"ViewControllerB" bundle=nil];
    viewControllerB.data = self.data;
    [self pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're adding the button to the nav bar. If you're adding it in interface builder you can simple link the action to the button in the connections inspector. However, if you want to create the button and link it to the action programmatically, use this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Review e-mail" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(reviewEmailButtonWasPushed:)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myButton];
```

Comment: And I suppose you would add the button in ViewDidLoad? Also, forgive my ignorance but how does the ViewController "know" that it's possible to add items to what I presume is its parent?

Comment: And yes, viewDidLoad will do it.